# How to inspect memory region of a core dump with Delve?

Tags: go, gdb, delve

Given a core dump of a Go service, is there any command on Delve that can inspect memory region?
We are trying to find out what is occupying the heap.

Comment: why dont you do a memory profile? it is buildin in go

Comment: @Pizzalord Unfortunately we didn't expose pprof endpoint on production, so we only can depend on core dump for post-mortem analysis..

Answer (score 1):

Last time I came across the similar problem, I found this little package https://github.com/golang/debug. It allows to get a histogram of a heap & inspect how many object of a specific type you had right before the crash.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work out of the box and you have to apply a couple of fixes which you find on the Pull Requests page

Comment: Very cool tool! but do you know why I get a bunch of "unk" objects when running "histogram"? for example: "unk1152", "unk704", "unk288", etc. Please advise if there is some way to interpret these objects. update: seems like these refer to "unknown", wondering if there is any way to increase the "readability" of these objects

Comment: Yes, "unk1152" means unknown type & 1152 means size of the instance. Unfortunately, I don't know how one can improve "type detection" in this particular case(

Comment: I figured out some workaround for this, I use `objects` command to list all live objects, get the address of one of the "unk" type, and then do `reachable <address>`. It is able to print some file location. Might need to run this several times on different addresses to confirm the finding, time consuming, but it works )

Comment: nice, would be keep this mind the next time. Thanks for sharing!